# Why is my resized SVG icon blurry when rendered?

Tags: html, css, svg, scale

I used Illustrator to create an SVG icon. 
Pasting this icon inline and resized into my HTML code makes the image blurry.

This issue occurs with Firefox, Chrome, and Edge.

[image: Demonstration image]

```css
body {
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    height: 100vh;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100vw;
}
svg {
  height: 22px;
  width: 22px;
}
svg:hover path {fill: tomato;}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 16 16"><path d="M15.6 11.9H6v-1.2c0-.4-.3-.7-.7-.7H3.8c-.4 0-.7.3-.7.7v1.2H.4c-.1 0-.2.1-.2.2v.5c0 .1.1.2.2.2h2.7V14c0 .4.3.7.7.7h1.5c.4 0 .7-.3.7-.7v-1.2h9.5c.1 0 .2-.1.2-.2v-.5c.1-.1 0-.2-.1-.2zm-10.5 2h-1V11h1v2.9zM15.6 3.1H8V1.9c0-.4-.3-.7-.7-.7H5.8c-.4 0-.7.3-.7.7v1.2H.4c-.1 0-.2.1-.2.2v.5c0 .1.1.2.2.2h4.7v1.2c0 .5.3.8.7.8h1.5c.4 0 .7-.3.7-.7V4.1h7.6c.1 0 .2-.1.2-.2v-.6c0-.1-.1-.2-.2-.2zM7 5.1H6v-3h1v3zm8.6 2.4h-2.7V6.3c0-.4-.3-.7-.7-.7h-1.5c-.4 0-.7.3-.7.7v1.2H.4c-.1 0-.2.1-.2.2v.5c0 .1.1.2.2.2H10v1.2c0 .4.3.7.7.7h1.5c.4 0 .7-.3.7-.7V8.5h2.7c.1 0 .2-.1.2-.2v-.5c0-.2-.1-.3-.2-.3zm-3.7 2h-1v-3h1v3z"/></svg>
```

I already tried adding

- `shape-rendering="geometricPrecision"` or `width="100%"` to the `svg` tag,
- `shape-rendering="crispEdges"` to `path` and
- `transform: translateZ(0);` to the svg style

but nothing makes the vector icon crisp.

Making the icon smaller or larger doesn't help. Using

```
svg {
  height: 42px;
  width: 42px;
}
```

still shows a blurry SVG icon.

Any ideas how to get the scaled vector image sharp?

Example code on CodePen: https://codepen.io/dash/pen/LYPxBPJ

Comment: maybe its my old poor eyes, but I don't see it as blurry. Can you provide an example of what its suppose to look like?

Comment: looks crisp to me

Comment: Your minimum stroke witdh is 1/16th of the SVG....I'd have started with a larger SVG and used a smaller stroke size.

Comment: The viewBox size is very small only 16/16. Also the icon size is too small: 22/22. Google's smallest icons are 24/24. I've loaded your svg in illustrator and changed the artboard size to 500/500. Also I've changed the icon size to 24/24. The blur disappeared

Comment: What @enxaneta said. If your coordinates need to be in fractional units, that's usually a sign that you've accidentally mistaken SVG for having "real dimensions". As vector graphics, they don't. Pick a size that comfortably allows integer coordinates, at dimensions that downscale cleanly. E.g. if you know the SVG is going to be rendered at 32x32, "draw" in a 640x640 quad. And then set the `width` and `height` attributes, _which you forgot to add here_, to the on-page dimensions (e.g. "32px").

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason it is "blurry" is due to anti-aliasing.  When the edge of a line or shape only partly covers a pixel, the browser approximates that partial coverage by drawing a semi-translucent pixel.

For example, if your background is white and the edge of a black shape only covers half a pixel.  That will be approximated by setting that pixel to 50% grey.

Your icon is being drawn at 22x22 pixels.  If I blow up your icon design 20x and overlay a 22x22 pixel grid.  You should be able to see what is happening.

```css
div {
  position: relative;
}
div > * {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

svg {
  height: 440px;
  width: 440px;
}

svg:not(.grid) {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <svg class="grid" viewBox="0 0 22 22" fill="none" stroke="red" stroke-width="0.045">
    <path d="M0,0 h22v1h-22v1 h22v1h-22v1 h22v1h-22v1 h22v1h-22v1 h22v1h-22v1 h22v1h-22v1 h22v1h-22v1 h22v1h-22v1 h22v1h-22v1 h22v1h-22v1 h22v1h-22v1 h22"/>
    <path d="M0,0 v22h1v-22h1 v22h1v-22h1 v22h1v-22h1 v22h1v-22h1 v22h1v-22h1 v22h1v-22h1 v22h1v-22h1 v22h1v-22h1 v22h1v-22h1 v22h1v-22h1 v22h1v-22h1 v22"/>
  </svg>

  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 16 16"><path d="M15.6 11.9H6v-1.2c0-.4-.3-.7-.7-.7H3.8c-.4 0-.7.3-.7.7v1.2H.4c-.1 0-.2.1-.2.2v.5c0 .1.1.2.2.2h2.7V14c0 .4.3.7.7.7h1.5c.4 0 .7-.3.7-.7v-1.2h9.5c.1 0 .2-.1.2-.2v-.5c.1-.1 0-.2-.1-.2zm-10.5 2h-1V11h1v2.9zM15.6 3.1H8V1.9c0-.4-.3-.7-.7-.7H5.8c-.4 0-.7.3-.7.7v1.2H.4c-.1 0-.2.1-.2.2v.5c0 .1.1.2.2.2h4.7v1.2c0 .5.3.8.7.8h1.5c.4 0 .7-.3.7-.7V4.1h7.6c.1 0 .2-.1.2-.2v-.6c0-.1-.1-.2-.2-.2zM7 5.1H6v-3h1v3zm8.6 2.4h-2.7V6.3c0-.4-.3-.7-.7-.7h-1.5c-.4 0-.7.3-.7.7v1.2H.4c-.1 0-.2.1-.2.2v.5c0 .1.1.2.2.2H10v1.2c0 .4.3.7.7.7h1.5c.4 0 .7-.3.7-.7V8.5h2.7c.1 0 .2-.1.2-.2v-.5c0-.2-.1-.3-.2-.3zm-3.7 2h-1v-3h1v3z"/></svg>
</div>
```

You can see that most of the shapes in your icon do not align with pixel boundaries.  Their edges pass through the middle of pixels.

The icon you are using was designed to be displayed at 16x16 - or a multiple of that.
If we overlay a 16x16 grid over it this time, you will see the shapes mostly align with pixel boundaries.

```css
div {
  position: relative;
}
div > * {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

svg {
  height: 320px;
  width: 320px;
}

svg:not(.grid) {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <svg class="grid" viewBox="0 0 16 16" fill="none" stroke="red" stroke-width="0.045">
    <path d="M0,0 h22v1h-22v1 h22v1h-22v1 h22v1h-22v1 h22v1h-22v1 h22v1h-22v1 h22v1h-22v1 h22v1h-22v1 h22v1h-22v1 h22v1h-22v1 h22v1h-22v1 h22v1h-22v1 h22"/>
    <path d="M0,0 v22h1v-22h1 v22h1v-22h1 v22h1v-22h1 v22h1v-22h1 v22h1v-22h1 v22h1v-22h1 v22h1v-22h1 v22h1v-22h1 v22h1v-22h1 v22h1v-22h1 v22h1v-22h1 v22"/>
  </svg>

  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 16 16"><path d="M15.6 11.9H6v-1.2c0-.4-.3-.7-.7-.7H3.8c-.4 0-.7.3-.7.7v1.2H.4c-.1 0-.2.1-.2.2v.5c0 .1.1.2.2.2h2.7V14c0 .4.3.7.7.7h1.5c.4 0 .7-.3.7-.7v-1.2h9.5c.1 0 .2-.1.2-.2v-.5c.1-.1 0-.2-.1-.2zm-10.5 2h-1V11h1v2.9zM15.6 3.1H8V1.9c0-.4-.3-.7-.7-.7H5.8c-.4 0-.7.3-.7.7v1.2H.4c-.1 0-.2.1-.2.2v.5c0 .1.1.2.2.2h4.7v1.2c0 .5.3.8.7.8h1.5c.4 0 .7-.3.7-.7V4.1h7.6c.1 0 .2-.1.2-.2v-.6c0-.1-.1-.2-.2-.2zM7 5.1H6v-3h1v3zm8.6 2.4h-2.7V6.3c0-.4-.3-.7-.7-.7h-1.5c-.4 0-.7.3-.7.7v1.2H.4c-.1 0-.2.1-.2.2v.5c0 .1.1.2.2.2H10v1.2c0 .4.3.7.7.7h1.5c.4 0 .7-.3.7-.7V8.5h2.7c.1 0 .2-.1.2-.2v-.5c0-.2-.1-.3-.2-.3zm-3.7 2h-1v-3h1v3z"/></svg>
</div>
```

In order to get the best/sharpest results for your icons, you should:

- Display your icons at the size they were intended (16x16)
- Find, or create a new icon set that is designed for 22x22
- Many icon sets are designed for 24x24 display. Perhaps you could switch to using one of those sets instead (and display them at 24x24)